# php and mysql form connection and inserting error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a form to save the 'id' and the 'eventname' to save in the database. i'm trying to save the form data into the table but not able to..here's the database code and the form code. please help. i tried but not able to try out the problem. I'm not getting any error but the data's what i enter in the form is not getting saved into the database..

```
   //table structure
    CREATE TABLE `event` (
    `Memberid` int(7) NOT NULL,
    `events` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

//form code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{ 
// database connection
$host_name =  'localhost';
$host_user = 'root';
$host_pass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($host_name, $host_user, $host_pass);
if(! $conn ){
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
    //code for SQL injection
    if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
    $login = addslashes ($_POST['login']);
    $eventList = addslashes ($_POST['eventList']);
    } else {
        $login = $_POST['login'];
        $eventList = $_POST['eventList'];
        } 

 //inserting data into the database table
 $sql = "INSERT INTO EVENT " . "(login, eventList) " . "VALUES " .('$login','$eventList')";
mysql_select_db('database');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
} 
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
} else
{ 
?>
<div class="container">
<!-- Codrops top bar -->
<section class="main">
   <form class="form-3" method="POST" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
     <p class="clearfix">
    <label for="login">Username</label>
       <input type="text" name="login" id="login" placeholder="Username">
 </p>
     <p class = "clearfix">
     <label for="select">Event Name</label>
   <select style="width:200px;" name="eventList" tabindex="5">
     <option value="select">Select Event</option>
    <optgroup label="Do Re Me">
       <option value="Battle of Bands">Battle of Bands</option>
        <option value="Eastern">Eastern</option>
        <option value="Solo">Solo</option>
       </optgroup>
   </select> <br>
</p>
<p class="clearfix">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign in">
</p>       
</form>
</section>
</div>
<?php 
} 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Syntax highlighter says some syntax error..

Comment: can u please let me know the erros..

Comment: Please improve the quality of this question. Atleast add what errors are you getting? What did you expect to happen etc. Reproduce the bug with as little code as possible, this is not a fix my broken code service.

Comment: use this line for insert $sql = "INSERT INTO EVENT (login, eventList) VALUES ('$login','$eventList')";